# How do we get rid of "upvote-rings" ..?

Tags: discussion

I see an increasing number of stupid questions ridiculously upvoted, and socalled "answers" incomprehensible upvoted. How can we avoid that?

Reason: Misuse of the system and the whole Stack-concept.

Comment: Custom moderator flags. Some moderators have become very good at destroying voting rings.

Comment: You want to specifically avoid it when it involves people from India? A bit misleading and oddly specific reference that.

Comment: @S.L.Barth, I do flag when it is obvious, but we have a problem with questions upvoted to 4, and the answer (immediately posted) upvoted to 3. It is not worth flagging, because the flag wil never be accepted. Trust me, I have a record of 657 helpful flags.  I do know what is triggering an accepted flag.

Comment: I'd have posted an answer if I thought flagging was enough. But, if question and answer are upvoted to 3 or 4 immediately, those flags aren't marked helpful? If I were a mod, I'd be _very_ suspicous of immediate voting. In fact, I've flagged just that kind of thing in the past, with success.

Comment: @davidkonrad I can't see a declined flag in your history where you've raised a custom moderator flag describing suspicious voting (or having said that - any flag at all mentioning it) - so not sure what your point is there... However, regardless of the location/supposed location of things, there's no harm in raising a flag and pointing it out.

Comment: @Gimby, read again. I do understand, that less knowledgeable people could think of this as a "racist" act. But it is people from India who are doing this. I have not seen this behavioir from people from other countries or regions.

Comment: @davidkonrad while it's true there are certain areas of the world which tend to indulge in such things more than others - the general gist behind the question remains the same and the location is redundant as the answer remains the same - use a custom flag and explain what you suspect is going on.

Comment: @JonClements, and you looked of course at my rejected  / disputed record :) No? I know it is not worth to flag a question with 6 upvotes and an accepted answer with 4 upvotes. You, the admins, say "An administrator have looked into that and see no reason to ..."

Comment: @davidkonrad is that not what I said in my previous comment: *I can't see a declined flag in your history where you've raised a custom moderator flag describing suspicious voting (or having said that - any flag at all mentioning it)* ? Don't conflate raising flags and their statuses for something else and the issue you raise here.

Comment: @JonClements, So, if you cant detect a flag in my record, the problem does not exist?

Comment: @davidkonrad no - you stated: *It is not worth flagging, because the flag wil never be accepted. Trust me, I have a record of 657 helpful flags. I do know what is triggering an accepted flag.* I'm pointing out that you've never raised a flag to have it accepted/declined explicitly stating you suspect suspicious voting so your assertion that flagging won't be accepted is based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: @JonClements, now we are talking semantics. I have never stated a flag on such premises, but this is just an overall judgement of how the system works. A question with 4 upvotes will never be removed (trust me) and a answer with 4 upvotes will never be deleted. This is how you, the admins works. This is why I ask this question.

Comment: *A question with 4 upvotes will never be removed (trust me) and a answer with 4 upvotes will never be deleted* - that's correct if there's no reason to remove them (and flagging them because it's not a good answer or a duplicate question isn't a reason). If they're posted purely for voting upon (which normally means they're spam-seeds or not useful/plagiarised content) then yes-  they will be removed... *trust me*

Comment: "I have never tried X, but I know how X works, just trust me" is rarely a good argument. It's even worse when you're arguing with someone who's responsible for implementing X. Maybe you should actually try the advice you're receiving before dismissing it.

Comment: @davidkonrad Even if some of them don't get removed, the account will be banned forever, their internet points will ge bone.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I'm just a moderator - so I'm not responsible for "implementing" anything... Although, like the rest of the moderator team, I try my hardest to make sure people don't get to keep their ill gotten reputation points (or if necessary their account) when it comes to light either in the moderator tools, or I'll iterate the point pertinent to the question here for the OP -  **when the community flags it and raises their concerns**

Comment: @JonClements As one of the people handling the flags you're recommending raising, that's effectively implementing that policy, no?

Comment: @ChrisHayes supposed it could be viewed as such... Need some more coffee and wake up properly :)

Comment: Edited out evident racism. Next time, don't associate a whole country where 40% of our traffic originates with a few of its members.

Comment: @davidkonrad You've got the answer to your question. I strongly suggest you go take a breather - that attitude isn't helping anyone.

Comment: @JonClements, Yes, I did that - good advice.